# profile name is not valid

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have created the following trigger in the AdventureWorks database:

```
CREATE TRIGGER special_offer_4
ON [Sales].[SpecialOffer] 
AFTER INSERT
AS
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
              @profile = 'DB SALMA',
              @recipients = 'someone@example.com',
              @body = ' Oh no...somebody just got more than an 80% discount!!!',
              @subject = 'Warning'

    INSERT INTO [Sales].[SpecialOffer] ([Description], [DiscountPct], [Type], [Category],
                                        [StartDate], [EndDate], [MinQty], [MaxQty])
        SELECT 
            [Description], [DiscountPct], [Type], [Category],
            [StartDate], [EndDate], [MinQty], [MaxQty] 
        FROM 
            inserted 
        WHERE 
            [DiscountPct] >= 0.80

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

It's supposed to send an email when someone tries to insert a discount of more than 0.80 like this:

```
INSERT INTO [Sales].[SpecialOffer]
 ([Description],
 [DiscountPct],
 [Type],
 [Category],
 [StartDate],
 [EndDate],
 [MinQty],
 [MaxQty])
  VALUES 
  ('Special Offer' , '0.80', 'special discount','customer', '2005-06-01 00:00:00.000','2008-12-31 00:00:00.000', '15', '40')
```

Whenever I try to execute this I get the following message :

> Msg 14607, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sysmail_verify_profile_sp, Line 129
> Profile name is not valid
>
> Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 88
> The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

I don't know how to fix this!

Comment: For a start, you need to add semicolons between each statement.

Comment: Why do you have _only_ a  `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`? Why don't you have a `COMMIT TRANSACTION`?

Comment: Also, triggers run in the context of an existing transaction - so you really shouldn't be doing `ROLLBACK` nor `COMMIT` inside a trigger, imo. If there's an error then you should use `THROW`.

Comment: What happens when you run the `exec send mail` on its own, and *why* are you inserting rows into the table in the trigger and why are you rolling back exclusively?

Comment: The error says profile name is not valid. The profile 'DB SALMA' must probably be declared somewhere to make the send function work.

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info) if I am honest. A `TRIGGER` should never be sending emails, and it should not be rolling back the transaction. If there is an error, you should be `THROW`ing an error and the calling code should be handling the problem.

Comment: Also, when you *do* `ROLLBACK` that transaction, you `ROLLBACK` the `INSERT` into `[Sales].[SpecialOffer]` within your `TRIGGER` as well; making the trigger completely pointless.

Comment: it may be good for you to add logging steps into your trigger. Things will be very easy in that way.